# command to assign NIC name to a variable

Tags: powershell

I got a command here to get the NIC details,But how will I call active NIC to a variable ?

```
PS C:\> netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces

Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
  1          50  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
 12           5        1500  connected     **Local Area Connection**
```

I want only Local Area Connection to be mapped to variable.

Note : The adapter name will differ from each machine.some machine it will be Ethernet/Ethernet 2\Local Area Connection etc

Comment: get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter ? It will fetch all the adapters and also you can check the adapter details

Comment: This command will not run on all flavors of operating system I guess

Comment: What do you mean by '*all flavor of operating systems*', does that include non-Windows OSes like Linux?

Comment: the command which works in all windows platform is netsh command which I mentioned above. But I am not sure how I can query the active adapter name to a variable . I tried below command, but doesnt work

Comment: $AdaptersNames = netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces |? {$_.state -eq "connected" -or $_.state -eq "Disconnected"} | Select -Expandproperty name

Comment: @Sandeep: I would like you to go through the PS documentation for wmi. All windows version support wmic and thereby it supports get-wmiobject also. If you are bothered about PS version then that anytime you can check.

Comment: `Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter` works since at least Windows XP. What other versions do you think you need to support?

Comment: `netsh` generates string output, so there is no property `Name` to expand. You'd need to parse the names out of the strings yourself, which I wouldn't recommend unless you have very compelling reasons to do so. Use WMI. It'll give you exactly what you want.